# Cannot use ADB on a bricked phone

Tags: adb, unbricking, fastboot, lenovo

I'm trying to unbrick a soft-bricked Android phone, and many tutorials say to use ADB to fix it, but I cannot use ADB or fastboot, since the device is not reconized. It's a Lenovo Zuk Z1, I am running Lubuntu, and it bricked because i formatted every single partition with CWM recovery, I can go into Zuk Recovery and download mode.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! If you really wiped every single partition, your device has no OS anymore – you will need to flash a ROM. See: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: I have already tried to flash a new ROM with fastboot and heimdall. That is my exact problem, I can't do anything on it now.

Comment: I don't know that device; but can't you flash a ROM from within CWM?

Comment: I suppose I can, but i cannot go into CWM anymore.

Comment: Argh. So you wiped `/recovery` as well? Uh-oh. Sorry, in that case I'm out. That doesn't leave many choices (if any at all except for JTAG). Guess you've successfully created a paperweight :( You could try customer care and ask whether there's the possibility to boot from an SD card (that way I was able to resurrect a tablet in a comparable situation); apart from that, no more ideas here, sorry.

Comment: There is no SD slot on this phone. Don't worry, thanks for your help!

Comment: Anytime. I'd still ask them – maybe they've got a work-around booting via OTG (though I'm not sure whether that's even possible on Android devices). Good luck!